# "check all" not checking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i used JQuery while i am trying to check all function then there because of this js not showing all checked field but while i removed that js then slider affected. So please try to sort out my problem i used no conflict function also but its not work.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict()
        jQuery.ready(function() {
            jQuery("#selectall").click(function() {
                $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
            }); // prototype
        });
    </script>

<div class="accordion-heading">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" name="sample" class="selectall" />
    <div style="float:left; "> <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_1" /> Admin Module
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="collapse_1" class="accordion-body collapse in">
    <div class="accordion-inner" id="checkboxlist">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="test" align="center" style="width:100%">
            <tr>

                <th width="450"><strong>Form Name</strong>
                </th>
                <th width="150"><strong>select</strong>
                </th>
                <th width="150"><strong>Edit</strong> </th>
                <th width="150"><strong>Delete</strong>
                </th>
                <th width="150"><strong>View</strong>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left:20%">Authentication</td>
                <td style="padding-left:8%">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="case1" name="emailid[]" value="" class="case" /> </td>
                <td style="padding-left:8%">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="case1" name="emailid[]" value="" class="case" />
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left:8%">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="case1" name="emailid[]" value="" class="case" /> </td>
                <td style="padding-left:8%">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="case1" name="emailid[]" value="" class="case" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: conflict java script

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You're simpy doing it wrong, only the current document has a ready handler, and you should be using `prop` to set a property, and listen for the `change` event when it's a checkbox.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#selectall").on('change', function () {
         $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Remember to actually include jQuery before your script

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/17cbt24v/1/)

Comment: Did you try the Fiddle, seems to work just fine for me ?

Comment: can you tell me where i used change .??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is how you should deal with jQuery.noConflict() :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
// Here, $ is a reference to whatever it was assign (if I understand correctly, it is prototypeJS)
(function($) {
    // Here, $ is a reference to jQuery
    $(function($) {
        $("#selectall").click(function() {
            $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
        }); // jQuery
    });
})(jQuery);
// Here, $ is a reference to whatever it was assign (if I understand correctly, it is prototypeJS)
</script>
```